# UI looks different between editor and in game

Tags: unity, gui, menu

I am very confused about Unity's UI system.

This is how my inventory menu looks in the Editor:

[image: In Editor]

And this is the view in game:

[image: In Game]

**Settings**

[image: Settings]

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it, I had to change the rect transform of `Panel_Slots` to stretch height:

[image]

Comment: Most Unity UI layout problems are caused by designing in one resolution and playing in another. When I design UIs in Unity I usually do that by detaching the scene window and constantly changing its size around after every change. That way I notice quite quickly if some part of the layout doesn't respond to different resolutions.

Comment: I think the answer to all problems is simply to use stretch everytime.